# How to Convert Cursive written Image into word Document?

Tags: image-processing

I have some image documents which are in cursive written. I need to convert these to word documents.. Any converter or anything else to do this process? Please help me soon.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

[Use it](http://kishor-naik-dotnet.blogspot.in/2012/05/cnet-read-text-from-image-in-cnet.html)

[Or you can try some of theese programs](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-5-free-ocr-software-tools-to-convert-your-images-into-text-nb/)